# Cast function pointers that differs by argument type

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers

Why this is not legal:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base(){};
};

class Derived : public Base{};

void takeDerived(Derived * c){};

// main
void(*ptr)(Base*) = static_cast<void(*)(Base*)>(&takeDerived); // doesn't work

// but this work ok, as well as reinterpret_cast
// void(*ptr)(Base*) = (void(*)(Base*))(&takeDerived);
```

`Derived` is a `Base`. Why can't it be casted in function parameter? For example, I can do this easily even without casting:

```
void takeBase(Base* c){};
takeBase(new Derived{});
```

Comment: That would violate basic sanity. `takeDerived` expects a `Derived *`, but your `ptr` would accept *any* `Base`-derived pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just designed to be that way. A `Base` isn't a `Derived`. The ***is-a*** relationship for class derivation can't be reversed.

The type of a function parameter means "accept", while the type of an object means "fit". Casting the type of a function changes what it accepts. It's dangerous to allow a function to accept whatever isn't what it originally accepts.

Consider this code:

```
class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    int t;
    void useDerived() {}
};

void useDerived(Derived *d){
    d->useDerived();
}
```

What should happen if a `Base` object is passed?

```
Base b;
((void(*)(Base*))useDerived) (&b);
```

Even worse, what if another derivation of `Base` is passed?

```
class AnotherDerived : public Base {
    public:
    double t;
    void useDerived() {}
};
AnotherDerived ad;
((void(*)(Base*))useDerived) (&ad);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you're trying to do it the other way around. You cannot do

```
void takeDerived(Derived *c) { }

...

Base b;
takeDerived(&b);
```

The function pointer cast you're trying to do would enable these shenanigans; you could do

```
void (*ptr)(Base*) = takeDerived;
Base b;
ptr(&b); // Oops.
```

Then things would explode, and that would be bad.